# Registering User with Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I set up password grant (it's backend for an app). Now, I can send a post request to `oauth/token` and it works on Postman. However, what if I want to register user from the api too?

I understand I can use current `/register` route, however, then will I need to redirect the user back to the login page and he logs in again with his credentials?

Or in the RegisterController, in `registered()` function, should I do I redirect to the `oauth/token` route? (For this, please note that I am sending, all the 5 data in 'x-www-form-urlencoded' and it seems to work. However, do I need to separate some in headers? It's blurry for me, so just wanted to ask when I have the chance).

Or should I add something in the `oauth/token` method like [this guy](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-register-a-user-through-laravel-passport/replies/340022)? Actually, I tried to catch the posted `$request` data on `AccessTokenController@issueToken`method inside library, however I couldn't figure out how to manipulate the `parsedBody` array. If I trigger my register function from the actual library, how would I know if it's register or login?

Maybe I am missing out some information, but I couldn't find anything based on this topic. What is the proper way of handling registering user in Passport?

---

**Update:** Accepted answer shows the 'register' cycle; and below it I have added 'login' and 'refresh token' implementations. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your API create route as

```
Route::post('register','Api\UsersController@create');
```

And in UsersController create method `create()`

```
function create(Request $request)
{
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    $valid = validator($request->only('email', 'name', 'password','mobile'), [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        'mobile' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($valid->fails()) {
        $jsonError=response()->json($valid->errors()->all(), 400);
        return \Response::json($jsonError);
    }

    $data = request()->only('email','name','password','mobile');

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'mobile' => $data['mobile']
    ]);

    // And created user until here.

    $client = Client::where('password_client', 1)->first();

    // Is this $request the same request? I mean Request $request? Then wouldn't it mess the other $request stuff? Also how did you pass it on the $request in $proxy? Wouldn't Request::create() just create a new thing?

    $request->request->add([
        'grant_type'    => 'password',
        'client_id'     => $client->id,
        'client_secret' => $client->secret,
        'username'      => $data['email'],
        'password'      => $data['password'],
        'scope'         => null,
    ]);

    // Fire off the internal request. 
    $token = Request::create(
        'oauth/token',
        'POST'
    );
    return \Route::dispatch($token);
}
```

And after creating new user, return access token.

Comment: This answers surelly works. but it does not check witch client app is making the request

Comment: It seemed to work fine for at least a year now but a few days ago there was an update because adding parameters to the request are not added to nyholm/psr7 ServerRequest so I'm getting invalid credentials error every time.
Did anybody else encounter this? Is there maybe a different approach ?

Answer (score 10):

And after I year, I figured out how to implement the full cycle.

@Nileshsinh method shows the register cycle.

And here is login & refresh token parts:

```
Route::post('auth/token', 'Api\AuthController@authenticate');
Route::post('auth/refresh', 'Api\AuthController@refreshToken');
```

Methods:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    private $client;

    /**
     * DefaultController constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = DB::table('oauth_clients')->where('id', 1)->first();
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $request->request->add([
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'username' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'client_id' => $this->client->id,
            'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
            'scope' => ''
        ]);

        $proxy = Request::create(
            'oauth/token',
            'POST'
        );

        return \Route::dispatch($proxy);
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function refreshToken(Request $request)
    {
        $request->request->add([
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token' => $request->refresh_token,
            'client_id' => $this->client->id,
            'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
            'scope' => ''
        ]);

        $proxy = Request::create(
            'oauth/token',
            'POST'
        );

        return \Route::dispatch($proxy);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i have 2 questions: `1` why do you get static user id in `__construct` part? `2` why should we refresh the token?(i mean the benefit is what?)

Comment: @mafortis - `1` - It is the `oauth_client` id for your app. Think it as you use any 3rd party api. When you sign up, you first sign up your application for API Key, API secret, right? (Think FaceBook api for example, you get credentials for your application). It's same here. `OAuth Client` is that. However, as I didn't want to open my api to public, I didn't have a lot of oauth clients, so I just fetch it. Otherwise, (if I was going to have many oauth clients), then I'd accept the App's OAuth credentials (api key & api secret), together as user credentials.

Comment: `2` - refresh token is just for security, because as token is the 'authentication' of any user, if someone else has his token, he can impersonate that user :) That's why it's good to refresh token :) (Big companies expire tokens in 10~ mins afaik) - Hope this helps :)

Comment: Well explained and worth giving a try: http://voerro.com/en/tutorials/r/building-spas-with-laravel-5-and-vuejs-2/1

Answer (score 3):

Reading this while Laravel 6 has recently been deployed, my solution for this is as following.

When you've followed the steps defined in Laravel's [passport documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport) and you added the `HasApiTokens` trait to the `User` model, you can call a `createToken` function on your user entities.

Also, in your `RegisterController` there's a `registered` function from the `RegistersUsers` trait that you can implement which is called when a user is successfully registered. So you could implement this as following:

```
protected function registered(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $token = $user->createToken('tokenName');

    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
        'token' => $token->accessToken,
    ]);
}
```

See the `register` function in the `RegistersUsers` trait for more information about the registration cycle..

Comment: but this seems to generate a personal token not access token or refresh token.

Comment: This is not password grant as asked in the question

Comment: I wonder why there is no full working tutorial on the Laravel documentation about how to make a simple register/login with passport using laravel's built in auth middleware... I have been fighting with this for years.